# Listen system proxy setting change

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My windows .NET WPF program needs to handle the System Proxy setting change. Which located in **Settings -- Network & Internet -- Proxy**.

How to register the System Proxy setting change listener. Let application receive a notification after the setting has been changed

Comment: You don't really, and there is none. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: My program will set the system proxy (such as 127.0.0.1: xxxx) and prompt the proxy running/stopped status with a taskbar icon.
When the user turns off the proxy in the setting panel, I want my taskbar icon also showing "stopped".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until someone steps in with a crazy windows api call from the 80s, you'll have to 'build your own'.

Read the value every quarter of a second, if it ever changes, huzzah.

Comment: “None” can also be an answer, it has made the question clear.

Answer (score 0):

System proxy data could be found under "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" in windows registry, the value "ProxyEnable" give you the proxy status, check for other values under that key and just be sure you are monitoring width a proper-desired interval. But all coding is up to you.[Registry proxy data IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWwKJ.png)